# Determining the Location Accuracy for InMobi iOS Ads

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, cllocation, inmobi

I am using the InMobi SDK to provide some native ads for iOS. Within their documentation they have the following, for setting the location of the ad to provide more relevant data.

> It should contain the latitude, longitude, and accuracy, separated by
> commas. This parameter is required if the request is needed to be
> considered for geo-targeting. The accuracy value should be "0" if the
> correct accuracy value is unavailable. Here, the accuracy is the
> radial accuracy of the lat-long data provided. More information on how
> to determine accuracy value is listed here.
>
> > http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees

To gain the user location I use Core Location and the `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` param. How do I work out/know what to send as the location accuracy for InMobi based on this parameter?

InMobi Doc Ref - https://www.inmobi.com/support/monetization/?page_id=12&id=29129146&parentid=22884296

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.inmobi.com/support/art/26555436/22465648/api-2-0-integration-guidelines/#geo

**accu** (integer) is the parameter, which comes from the parent object (JSON) **geo**

ie:

```
//when using CoreLocation to fetch the coordinate
CLLocationManager *mgr = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
CLLocation *loc = mgr.location;
[InMobi setLocationWithLatitude:loc.coordinate.latitude longitude:loc.coordinate.longitude accuracy:loc.horizontalAccuracy];
[locationMgr startUpdatingLocation];
```

or

```
InMobi setLocationWithLatitude:self.delegate.location.coordinate.latitude
longitude:self.delegate.location.coordinate.longitude
accuracy:self.delegate.location.horizontalAccuracy
```

Comment: Thanks I worked that out too. I decided to use `MAX(loc.horizontalAccuracy, loc.verticalAccuracy)` as the only difference